# How can I remove triangle icon (for expansion/collapse) for root node not having child node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am facing some difficulty with ui of jstree which would dynamically add/remove nodes when clicked on the node. It would add child nodes on first click and remove click nodes on second click on the same node. I am currently binding the jstree with selected_node event like this :

```
$(function () {
    $("#tree").jstree({ 
        "json_data" : {
            "data" : [
                { 
                    data : "/", 
                    attr : { "id" : "root"},
                    state : "closed",
                },
            ]
        },
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "crrm", "ui" ]
    }).bind("select_node.jstree", function(event, data) { 
        // . . . 
    }
```

Initially a node with folder icon with a small triangle on left side (for expansion) and the data value on the right side of folder icon. As there are no nodes of the tree initially I do not want the expansion feature i.e. the small triangle on left side. Can anybody help with that ? For child nodes when I click for the second time(that removes child nodes of child node) the triangle disappears. I am not able to understand the logic behind random display of triangle for expansion/collapse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to set the root node state to:

```
state: "leaf"
```

This way the node shouldn't show the expanding triangle.

Comment: Thanks so much @spiderman77 . I will keep this in mind from now one. But now that I have programmed everything without knowledge of method you told, it would be really helpful if you can tell how can I have a expanding triangle in front of node after its all child nodes are deleted.

Comment: I also do not know at all the internal logic of jstree (by the way that it would seem more logical not to have a disclosure triangle when the node has no children)
Anyway ... you could try to force the "open" style? (should work if jstree automatically applies internally to the node without children style "leaf")

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to hide the icon from css:

```css
#tree i {
  display: none;
}
```